# Options for Multiple Login (Google/Facebook/Twitter)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, openid, oauth-2.0

I am writing a webapp on Google App Engine with python and right now I am using the built in federated login system with OpenID and it works great with Google/Yahoo/AOL but I want to give users on Facebook and Twitter access to the site as well.  There have been questions like this in the past year or two but none have been fully answered or are out of date.

Basically all I want is for the user to be able to login with either of these three services and I want to be able to authenticate them and store a unique user_id along with each user.  I am not all that interested in posting to facebook walls or sending tweet updates from the site I simply want to give users a really easy way to login with existing accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought of using a library that provides this functionality? Something like simpleauth:

- https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth

Most of the boilerplate for new projects have this stuff built in too:

- http://green-algae.appspot.com/
- https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

Comment: Is SimpleAuth pretty stable and have a decent chance of continual development? I have seen it before and it is basically exactly what I want but I wanted to make sure

Comment: I can't predict the future but I can say it has been in development for 8 months and it is MIT licensed so even if he stopped development you could continue to tweak and update it for your needs. As to stability I can't speak from first hand experience as I have not used it directly. It does have a test suite but as with anything you should run your own tests once integrated. I wish I had useful info for you. A friend of mine uses gae-boilerplate for all his projects and has been very happy with its auth handling but I have not used that either.

Comment: Alright great well I appreciate the suggestions and I'm going to look into it.  SimpleAuth looks like just the right thing

Answer (score 2):

Even if a wake up an old thread, but for the records:

[Authomatic](https://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/) is a really complete authorization / authentication client library for Python web applications (including Google AppEngine).

Out of the box it supports about 29 different providers.

Answer (score 1):

Another great library is [Velruse](https://velruse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: do you have any working examples of what this looks like? it looks great but it also looks pretty involved to integrate

Comment: and do you know if it works well with Google App Engine instead of a Pyramid application

Comment: There are some great and simple examples in the package. Just implement those and grow from there. Velruse uses the 'requests' library, which in turn should be compatible with GAE according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762685/using-the-requests-python-library-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

I Have found another API [**HybridAuth**](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)

It comes with wonderful API, and PHP library,

The main advantage of using this is that it comes with several third party plugins such as [**CodeIgniter**](https://github.com/andacata/HybridIgniter),[**Wordpress**](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Plugin_WordPress_Social_Login.html),[**Zend**](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth),[**CakePHP**](https://github.com/hybridauth/CakePHP-HybridAuth),[**Joomla**](https://hs-shelf.com/item/UyLOnrdkO9sEg2S1hulA.html),[**Drupal**](http://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) and son on.

Have a try it's the best.