# Google Appengine: Requests Alternative

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, urllib3

I have a non-GAE application/request-handler that uses the Python requests module in a to post an uploaded imaged via a POST request, as binary:

```
headers = {"MyAuth" : "xyz"}
r = requests.post(base_uri, data=open('0.jpg')), headers=headers)
```

The user uploads an image, the uploaded image is saved locally, opened for reading, then sent to a remote classifier pipeline via post request - this returns some JSON regarding the image features, which can then be returned to the user.

I need to implement this behaviour in a GAE app, but know that GAE has no traditional file system,  so I will have to use `StringIO`:

```
data = ... #some jpg => str
headers = {"MyAuth" : "xyz"}
r = requests.post(base_uri, data=StringIO.StringIO(data), headers=headers)
```

How could I completely replace the requests module in this example in a GAE friendly way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although probably not the best solution to this problem,  I managed to get requests 2.3.0 to work in the GAE project with:

```
pip install --target myproject/externals/ requests==2.3.0
```

I can now use requests as I would normally.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly used module for making HTTP requests on app engine is [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch), it is available in the default runtime via `google.appengine.api.urlfetch`. Supposedly urllib2 and/or urllib3 are also options, but I have not used those myself so I can't say for sure.

You can also [install requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library) in your app engine directory and upload it with the project, but I find that a bit of a hassle, since requests has its own dependencies that you will need to include as well.

Also see [Using the Requests python library in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762685/using-the-requests-python-library-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I took a look at urlfetch and it got me most of the way, however the binary upload, whilst it did upload the data and return a 200,  the classifier could not extract any usable features from the data. Bizarre,  I'm clearly missing something very simple.  Unfortunately time is against me on this project, so I managed to get requests 2.3.0 working in production.