# SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, python-requests, wechat

Want to use [wechat sdk](http://wechat-python-sdk.readthedocs.org/zh_CN/master/basic.html) to create menu

```
WeChat.create_menu({
     "button":[
     {    
          "type":"click",
          "name":"Daily Song",
          "key":"V1001_TODAY_MUSIC"
      },
      {
           "type":"click",
           "name":" Artist Profile",
           "key":"V1001_TODAY_SINGER"
      },
      {
           "name":"Menu",
           "sub_button":[
           {    
               "type":"view",
               "name":"Search",
               "url":"http://www.soso.com/"
            },
            {
               "type":"view",
               "name":"Video",
               "url":"http://v.qq.com/"
            },
            {
               "type":"click",
               "name":"Like us",
               "key":"V1001_GOOD"
            }]
       }]
 })
```

Currently not work because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechatAPIHandler.py", line 72, in post
    "key":"V1001_GOOD"
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 355, in create_menu
    data=menu_data
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 949, in _post
    **kwargs
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 907, in _request
    "access_token": self.access_token,
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 849, in access_token
    self.grant_token()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 273, in grant_token
    "secret": self.__appsecret,
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 935, in _get
    **kwargs
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/wechat_sdk/basic.py", line 917, in _request
    **kwargs
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~project-boom/1.384461758981660124/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

python request module is include in the app engine project. Using python 2.7. Being look for ways to solve this problem but have not find very clear way to solve the problem yet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604799/can-python-requests-library-be-used-on-google-app-engine/28544823#28544823

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're using GAE's Sockets, you can get SSL support without any hacks by simply loading the SSL library.

Simply add this to your app.yaml file:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

This is documented on [Google Cloud's OpenSSL Support documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support)

Answer (score 12):

[This blog post details a solution](http://bekt.github.io/p/gae-ssl/#sthash.bnL4iKEq.dpbs). From the blog post:

> The problem is GAE has a “whitelist” of select standard libraries. SSL
>   (_ssl, _socket) is not one of them. So, we need to tweak the sandbox
>   environment (dangerous) carefully. The below code uses the standard
>   Python socket library instead of the GAE-provided in the development
>   environment. Modify [or create] appengine_config.py:

```
import os

# Workaround the dev-environment SSL
#   http://stackoverflow.com/q/16192916/893652
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    import imp
    import os.path
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox

    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']
    # Use the system socket.
    psocket = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.__file__), 'socket.py')
    imp.load_source('socket', psocket)
```

Comment: Why is such a fix required?  Isn't using SSL with Python on GAE a common use case?  I would imagine it is.  (Writing my first GAE app, myself.)

Comment: I agree, SSL should have been one the first libraries GAE python supported.

Answer (score 2):

Jan Dolejsi,

> If you're using GAE's Sockets, you can get SSL support without any
>   hacks by simply loading the SSL library.
>
> Simply add this to your app.yaml file:
>
> libraries:
>   - name: ssl
>   - version: latest

If you're experiencing RAND_egd error, just change "-version: latest" in your app.yaml, to "-version: 2.7"!