# facebookads api calling in google cloud appengine - SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, facebook-ads-api

I got a requirement to pull the facebookads data into bigquery. I need to create python script for appengine.

Python script standalone is working fine without any issues and got the required data. When I tried to call the same python script from appengine getting the following error.

Please help me with the below error.

Error Message:

```
ERROR    2017-06-08 21:22:10,816 webapp2.py:1528] Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\main.py", line 57, in get
    stats = ad_account.get_insights(params=params)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\adobjects\FBAdAccount.py", line 78, in get_insights
    return request.execute()
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\api.py", line 653, in execute
    cursor.load_next_page()
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\api.py", line 797, in load_next_page
    params=self.params,
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\api.py", line 305, in call
    timeout=self._session.timeout
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\requests\sessions.py", line 513, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\requests\sessions.py", line 623, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
ERROR    2017-06-08 21:22:10,822 wsgi.py:279]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\main.py", line 57, in get
    stats = ad_account.get_insights(params=params)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\adobjects\FBAdAccount.py", line 78, in get_insights
    return request.execute()
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\api.py", line 653, in execute
    cursor.load_next_page()
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\api.py", line 797, in load_next_page
    params=self.params,
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\facebookads\api.py", line 305, in call
    timeout=self._session.timeout
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\requests\sessions.py", line 513, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\requests\sessions.py", line 623, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Chaitu\Projects\fb\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
**SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.**
INFO     2017-06-08 17:22:12,344 module.py:809] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381581/sslerror-cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppEngine does support native Python OpenSSL. You need to modify your `app.yaml` based on which python version you're using.

How to add support for OpenSSL in your AppEngine services is [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support).

For `v2.7`:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: 2.7
```

For `v2.7.11`:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: 2.7.11
```