# Porting Basic Script on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I came across google app engine a week ago and wanted to play around with
it a bit. I wrote a dummy application which checks a url and based on
the return code it logs to a file if the site is "up" or "down"

I wanted to deploy it on to app engine and schedule cron jobs ( for example every one minute).
I came across this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine-sample/tree/master/gae). I complete understand the app.yaml file but I am not sure about the 
'url' int he cron.yaml file. WHat it is purpose? can it be skipped in the file?

Morover the example uses the webapp2 module. Do I wrap my code in that module?

Code given below:

```
import requests
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('testapp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/Users/me/Desktop/testlog.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    r = requests.head("http://www.redcafe.com")
    code = (r.status_code)
except requests.ConnectionError:
    logger.error('URL Error')

if code == 200:
    logger.info('Up and running')
else:
    logger.error('Cant find website')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [cron.yaml doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_About_cron_yaml):

> The **url** field specifies a URL in your application that will be
>   invoked by the Cron Service.

Basically your app will register a handler for that URL which will be invoked when the GAE cron service requests it.

You probably want to spend some time getting familiar at least with:

- [the GAE python runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) constraints (you can't directly write to a file, for example)
- [cron/scheduled tasks in GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron)
- [the GAE python tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction) which explains how **webapp2** fits into the picture

Using the **requests** library in GAE may be tricky: [Can Python Requests library be used on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604799/can-python-requests-library-be-used-on-google-app-engine)
You may want to take a look at the GAE [sockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/) or [URL fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) services as alternatives.