# TypeError: expected httplib.Message, got <type 'instance'>. when using requests.get(url) on GAE

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

My aim is to build a web crawler and host it on GAE. However,when I try to execute a very basic implementation I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\WSE_NewsClusteriing\crawler\crawler.py", line 14, in get
    source_code = requests.get(url)
  File "libs\requests\api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "libs\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "libs\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "libs\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "libs\requests\adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "libs\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "libs\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 390, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "libs\requests\packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 49, in assert_header_parsing
    type(headers)))
TypeError: expected httplib.Message, got <type 'instance'>.
```

My main.py is as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

import webapp2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'title-link'}):
            href = 'http://www.bbc.com' + link.get('href')
            self.response.write(href)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

The thing is that the crawler works fine as a standalone python application.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here? Does the requests module cause some compatibility issues with GAE?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/618.

Comment: Many issues reported when using the `requests` lib on GAE, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604799/can-python-requests-library-be-used-on-google-app-engine?lq=1 (check linked/related questions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would advise against using the `requests` library on App Engine for the time being as it is not officially supported. It is therefore very likely to encounter compatibility issues. As per the [URL Fetch Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) article, supported libraries include `urllib`, `urllib2`, `httplib` and using `urlfetch` directly. Some features of the `requests` library may also be based on the `urllib3` library given [their collaboration](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/dev/authors/#urllib3). This library is also not yet supported.

Feel free to consult the [URL Fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) for simple examples of `urllib2` and `urlfetch` requests. If there's some way that these libraries are not working for you, feel free to point us as such in your question.

Comment: Perhaps this was true in Mar 2016, but as of Dec 2017 Requests seems to be fully supported on GAE (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests), and indeed is given as the recommended HTTP transport to use when using `google_auth` with GAE (https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html). This particular error message will happen if you forget to "monkeypatch": see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994316/925478

Answer (score 8):

This is almost two years old question but I actually stumbled upon this on appengine just now.
For the benefit of those who may come across similar issue, docs describes how to issue HTTP(S) requests

```
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

# Use the App Engine Requests adapter. This makes sure that Requests uses
# URLFetch.
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
```

Referance https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests