# URLFetch Sessions GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project and chosen google app engine to host the script .

I am stucked in sessions . I have written the script using request module but since google appengine doesn't allow to use requests module so I've tried this

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
r = urlfetch.fetch("http://www.google.com")
data = { 'query' : 'search_query' }
r = urlfetch.fetch("http://www.google.com/search",headers=r.headers,method=urlfetch.POST,payload=data)
```

I have just given a example of what i trying to accomplish but it seems not working with cookies . The cookies get changed .

I got to know this because the `B` value get changed from `B=ff09f69f244d862c494236ed3d0c6e1c;` to `B=8b18c48e19c0352b52903c49c45a41d1;` which is not meant to be changed.

Comment: You can install the requests package.  You need to add it to your app files (say in a 'libs' directory), then it will upload when you deploy.  Where are you setting the r.headers?

Comment: It's throwing TypeError: expected httplib.Message, got <type 'instance'>. this error when i try to include requests module .

Comment: Yes, others have reported that.  I have not used requests urllib3, only use requests inside rauth.  You should try `urllib2.urlopen` method of scraping.

Comment: That's the only option ?

Comment: read these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604799/can-python-requests-library-be-used-on-google-app-engine?lq=1  https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/618

Comment: Thanks a lot bro i really appreciate this post it as answer and i will accept this :)

Comment: I don't have billing enabled ! Is there any other option :)

Comment: Well, you can enable billing, but set a very low budget.  That enables many features.

Comment: I tried requests 0.7.3 and it worked ! Thanks