# Firebase Auth verify_id_token error "super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type"

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Trying to use firebase auth as the authentication system. I have read through the [verify ID token docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and went through the [Firebase SDK Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). Using GAE and Datastore as backend, Python and webapp2 framework.

Whenever trying to verify id token

```
decoded_claims = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
```

I get the below warning and error (using Mac), *error happens when using the `auth` module in general, ex: when trying to use `get_user`, `get_user_by_email`...etc.*

**Warning**

```
Warning: urllib3 is using URLFetch on Google App Engine sandbox instead of sockets. To use sockets directly instead of URLFetch see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html.
```

**Error**

```
File /<mypath>/lib/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 26, in __init__
super(CacheControlAdapter, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
File "/<mypath>/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 121, in __init__
super(HTTPAdapter, self).__init__()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

The error seems to be related to the libraries `requests` and `cachecontrol` and not something related to our code. My guess is that this is related to the installation of some libraries which may have been missing some dependencies. We install all libraries to a `/lib` folder under our project as indicated [in the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) using:

`sudo pip install -t <path>/lib <library>`

Including the installation for firebase-admin *i.e.* `sudo pip install -t <path>/lib firebase-admin`

Updated the Firebase SDK to 2.12.0, tried removing and reinstalling Firebase auth, read through [Verify ID tokens using a third-party JWT library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third_party_jwt_library) *(still having problems getting it to work)* which seems like a workaround rather than using the Admin SDK directly and makes more sense. Anyone knows a solution around the `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` error?

**UPDATE 1**

Reading through [Another super() wrinkle – raising TypeError](https://thingspython.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/another-super-wrinkle-raising-typeerror/) regarding the *TypeError*, I checked line 121 in the file `adapters.py` as logged in the error output

`/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 123, in __init__
super(HTTPAdapter, self).__init__()`

and added print statements as noted in the above blog

```
print "HTTPAdapter", HTTPAdapter
print isinstance(self, HTTPAdapter)
```

and got the same False output result!

```
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
True
HTTPAdapter <class 'requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.AppEngineAdapter'>
False
```

So apparently this seems to be called multiple times and `isinstance` is failing for the last call which is raising the error.. 
Not sure why no one else seem to have encountered that when using Firebase auth with those libraries..

Comment: Have you installed the `requests-toolbelt`, and followed the additional set up instructions for App Engine? https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#the-app-engine-standard-environment

Comment: Yup, I did that earlier and followed the steps from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604799/can-python-requests-library-be-used-on-google-app-engine/37304524#37304524

Comment: I opened a python terminal and tried using the SDK directory from there (versus, running from local Google App Engine!) and it works from the terminal! So it is clearly something related to libraries and dependencies. since for GAE libraries are installed in a separate ```lib``` folder. I tried comparing some of the files from the system path to the ones in the GAE ```lib``` folder, ex: ```requests```, ```cachecontrol```, ```jwt``` but I believe they are either the same version or the ones in the ```lib``` are actually the updates ones!

Comment: Following through with some debugging, I stumbled upon https://thingspython.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/another-super-wrinkle-raising-typeerror/ which discusses when this error is thrown when using ```super``` and module reload occurs in the code. Not sure, why no one else had this error as it seems related to ```requests/adapters.py```module...

Comment: I tried removing firebase-admin (latest version 2.12.0) and reinstalled it again using version 2.9.0 instead ```pip install -t ./lib/ "firebase-admin==2.9.0"``` and function *get_user_by_phone_number* worked without errors! function *verify_id_token* is giving a permission denied error. Unfortunately, this means that the latest version doesn't work with this setup environment(!) that means newer functions like session cookies won't be accessible!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I have misplaced the `requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch` line in my code. I don't remember why it was moved down after importing firebase and credentials and auth. But for some reason it was moved down thus causing the error to happen.

**The wrong placement:**

```
import webapp2

import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth
import firebase_admin

cred = credentials.Certificate(myjson)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch() # <-- wrong placement!
```

**The correct placement:**

```
import webapp2

import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch() # <-- correct placement!

from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth
import firebase_admin

cred = credentials.Certificate(myjson)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Although embarrassing, but I will keep this here in case someone else faces the same issue!

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve it for me. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Can you use firebase_admin with a later version (>2.9.1)? Maybe that's the problem I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem but sadly the monkeypatching alone did not work for me what did work is switching firebase-admin to version 2.9.1